# Submit a SOAP request using python to an ESB endpoint

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, esb, wso2-esb

I need to send a certain request to ESB endpoint from python. Basically what I need is to invoke a service from ESB without going to the app 1st.

Please help and I can clarify further if requested.

Below I have attached the dummy request.

```
Server Time: 11:02:58:028 / Workstation Time: Monday, 22 February 2016 - 11:02:57:703
[DEBUG] SENDING SOAP REQUEST
MethodID: ID_getSubmitRequest; UID=-4820428854312736237
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns2:getSubmitRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:AC_IDM_SUBMITREQUESTVi" xmlns="urn:com.virsa.ae.ejbutil">
<ns2:requestDetails>
<application/>
<company>STACK OVERFLOW</company>
<customField>
<CustomFieldsDTO>
<name>Users ID Number</name>
<value>6303066107089</value>
</CustomFieldsDTO>
</customField>
<department xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<emailAddress>ronny.ronny@stack.co.za</emailAddress>
<employeeType>STACK</employeeType>
<firstName>RONNY</firstName>
<functionalArea xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<lastName>RONNY</lastName>
<locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<location xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<managerTelephone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrEmailAddress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrFirstName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<mgrLastName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<priority>HIGH</priority>
<requestReason xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<requestType>SYSTEM</requestType>
<requestorEmailAddress>None</requestorEmailAddress>
<requestorFirstName>None</requestorFirstName>
<requestorId>BP5151</requestorId>
<requestorLastName>None</requestorLastName>
<requestorTelephone>None</requestorTelephone>
<roles>
<RoleData>
<action>ADD</action>
<comments xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<roleId>ZCB_STACK</roleId>
<sysId/>
<validFrom>2016-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validFrom>
<validTo>9999-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validTo>
</RoleData>
</roles>
<sNCName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<telephone>0123456789</telephone>
<unsecureLogon>false</unsecureLogon>
<userId>BP111</userId>
<validFrom>2016-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validFrom>
<validTo>9999-02-22T11:02:57+02:00</validTo>
</ns2:requestDetails>
</ns2:getSubmitRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Edit : I managed to get module python module request and when I run the code I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Soap.py", line 79, in <module>
    verify=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Python Code :

```
import requests

request = u"""<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:getSubmitRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:SAPGRC_SUBMITREQUESTVi" xmlns="urn:com.virsa.ae.ejbutil">
         <ns2:requestDetails>
            <application/>
            <company>STACK OVERFLOW</company>
            <customField>
               <CustomFieldsDTO>
                  <name>Users ID Number</name>
                  <value>7706198530094</value>
               </CustomFieldsDTO>
            </customField>
            <department xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <emailAddress>ben.ten@standardbank.co.za</emailAddress>
            <employeeType>STACK</employeeType>
            <firstName>BEN</firstName>
            <functionalArea xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <lastName>TEN</lastName>
            <locale xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <location xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <managerTelephone xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <mgrEmailAddress xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <mgrFirstName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <mgrId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <mgrLastName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <priority>HIGH</priority>
            <requestReason xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <requestType>SYSTEM</requestType>
            <requestorEmailAddress>None</requestorEmailAddress>
            <requestorFirstName>None</requestorFirstName>
            <requestorId>BP296</requestorId>
            <requestorLastName>None</requestorLastName>
            <requestorTelephone>None</requestorTelephone>
            <roles>
               <RoleData>
                  <action>ADD</action>
                  <comments xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <company xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <roleId>ZCB_STACK_RTS</roleId>
                  <sysId/>
                  <validFrom>2017-05-10T10:57:27+02:00</validFrom>
                  <validTo>9999-05-10T10:57:27+02:00</validTo>
               </RoleData>
            </roles>
            <sNCName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <telephone>012345678</telephone>
            <unsecureLogon>false</unsecureLogon>
            <userId>BP9780</userId>
            <validFrom>2017-05-10T10:57:27+02:00</validFrom>
            <validTo>9999-05-10T10:57:27+02:00</validTo>
         </ns2:requestDetails>
      </ns2:getSubmitRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

headers = {"Host": "*endpoint to send the req*",
            "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8",
            "Content-Length": str(len(encoded_request)),
            "SOAPAction": ""}

response = requests.post(url="*endpoint to send the req*",
                     headers = headers,
                     data = encoded_request,
                     verify=False)

print response.content #print response.text
```

Comment: Get SoapUI installed. Enable http logging in settings. Then create new project. Make request. In console you will see all things needed to recreate http request (url, headers, body). Easiest library is http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Anyway it is actually simple. Create http POST request to url (find in wsdl of service). Make content-type application/xml, append header SOAPAction (value in service wsdl). Body what u need to send. Done

Comment: I'm really confused, I never worked with ESB before, I'm from front end side all I do is call a service from my java code but in this case trying to automate some processes using python.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is make proper http request. One of method is "**Do the same**"

Find out some how, how http request is made. Simplest in your case is to use SoapUI tool. It is a tool to test SOAP services. On of feature is configure it to show dump of tcp traffic in console. You will be able literally to see response request in raw format. (Good thing http is text format)

As i mention just make **POST** request, append **SOAPAction** header and set **Content-Type** header to **application/xml**. That is enought.

SOAPAction header and URL cant be taken from wsdl file, which is provided by WSOESB server.

This is a sketch and it might need some adjustment. It is Python3 based.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib

# 8280 default port if you didn't change configuration of esb server
# /services default path if you didn't change configuration of esb server
# YourServiceName - service name 

url = 'http://esb-server-host:8280/services/YourServiceName'
method='POST'

# default SOAPAction extected for CUSTOME ESB PROXY SERVICE

headers = {'SOAPAction':'urn:mediate', 'Content-Type':'application/xml'}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers, method=method)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   data = response.read()
   print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Simar, but now with the sketch where does the request go? There are arguments which I need to pass. and also when I view the wsdl I can't find the SOAPAction.

Comment: Enter to admin console http://server-address:9443/carbon. Default admin:admin. Click proxy services

Comment: Example is at image on step5. Description of default echo service. Blue link wsdl1.1 on "Client Operations"  http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/09/disabling-ws-security-for-in-or-out-messages-in-axis2/